# How to change make js button l with same function such as jsf-button?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have jsf code

```
 <p:commandButton action="#{reporting.downloadPaymentsReport}" value="Скачать" ajax="false"/>
```

Is there way to make same button on js?(without creating rest on server-side)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to make your button call a JSF controller function and a JS function?

You could use the `oncomplete` attribute like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="buttonExample"
   actionListener="#{reporting.downloadPaymentsReport}"
   oncomplete="jsFunction()"
   value="Скачать"
   />
```

(At our project we mostly use actionListener, no specific other reason I changed action to actionListener)

An example JS function:

```
function jsFunction() {
  console.log('test');
}
```

Put that function in a .js file and import in your xhtml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jsFile.js" />
```